# Author archive only for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, author, author-template

I want to create an author archive for only custom post type. This page will includes only custom posts by the author.

And url structure should be example.com/portfolio/author/author-name/

I don't want to include custom type to default author.php because my custom post type is in different language.

Comment: Someone else posted an answer to this question that I found even better, because it just appends the custom post type as a query to the URL for the author, thus loading the default archive page for the custom post type. [Take a look here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/290855/show-custom-post-type-by-author?newreg=30232ac56812481084f3eb29b0306f59).

Answer (score 3):

According to [this blogpost](https://premium.wpmudev.org/forums/topic/author-archives-for-custom-post-types-resources) you just need to add the following code to your themes `functions.php` or in a plugin:

```
/* Add CPTs to author archives */
function custom_post_author_archive($query) {
    if ($query->is_author)
        $query->set( 'post_type', array('custom_type', 'post') );
    remove_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_author_archive' );
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_author_archive');
```